# How to check two QLineEdit If they are not empty

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have three controls, two `QTextLine` and one `QPushButton`.

[image]

When startup the program, the add button will be disabled, and must be two `QTextLine` not empty for enable the add button.

I have the following code, but it does not works fine:

```
void Question_Answer::on_newQuestion_txt_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    if(arg1.isEmpty())
    {
        ui->addNewQuestion_btn->setEnabled(false);
    }
    else
    {
        ui->addNewQuestion_btn->setEnabled(true);
    }
}

void Question_Answer::on_newAnswer_txt_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    if(ui->newAnswer_txt->text().isEmpty())
    {
        ui->addNewQuestion_btn->setEnabled(false);
    }
    else
    {
        ui->addNewQuestion_btn->setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Now, How to check if the two `QTextLine` are not empty, and also if any of them is empty, how to disable the add button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just connect a single slot to handle `textChanged` signals of both `LineEdits`

```
void Question_Answer::onTextChanged(const QString &arg1){
    if(ui->newAnswer_txt->text().isEmpty() || ui->newQuestion_txt->text().isEmpty()){
        ui->addNewQuestion_btn->setEnabled(false);
    }else{
        ui->addNewQuestion_btn->setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but where can I put the connect method ?

Comment: You should already have added two `connect` calls. Just replace the slot of both of them to `onTextChanged`

Comment: Sorry, but can you give me an example. because I have used the design mode to adds the slots.

Comment: In QtDesigner, there is a pane named `Signals & Slots Editor` in the bottom. In that you can see the signal slot connections you already have made. There should be two connections for `textChanged` signal for `newAnswer_txt` and `newQuestion_txt`. Change the slot of both of them to `onTextChanged`.

Comment: What about receiver ?

Comment: Receiver should be `Question_Answer`, where you have added the slot. You will have to first add the `onTextChanged` slot to `Question_Answer` in editor. To do that, right click on the `Question_Answer` form and select `Change signals/slots` and add `onTextChanted()` to slots list.

Answer (score 0):

In the header class:

```
// ...
private slots:
    void onTextChanged();
// ...
```

In the source file:

```
// Setup the connections in the constructor.

void Question_Answer::onTextChanged()
{
    const bool editable1 = ui->newAnswer_txt->text().size() > 0;
    const bool editable2 = ui->newQuestion_txt->text().size() > 0;
    ui->addNewQuestion_btn->setEnabled( editable1 && editable2 );
}
```